# Is there any Mouse Event for Scrollbar

Tags: jquery-ui

I need to detect the move of horizontal scrollbar of a div.

Is there any specific mouse event for scrollbar of a div.

Answer (score 0):

Yes:

http://api.jquery.com/scroll/